# How to use ENUM with SWITCH, for String based comparison

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a Enum class as below.

```
public enum TestEnum {
    TEST1("test1"), TEST2("test2");

    private String name;
    TestEnum(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

I am trying to use it in SWITCH statement to compare against a String, but not able to use. See below screenshot, I only see `.class` option. And I am so much surprised because in one other box I can see the values.

[image]

Now, another issue I have is that lets say once I see values, I want to do `case TestEnum.TEST1.getName():` so that it can work with the switch statement, but here I get error saying that only constants are allowed for switch case.

Could someone please help on this. Basically, what I want that instead of checking a string against number of possible strings like "test1" or "test2" I want to do this using SWITCH.

As an aside, I have 32 IF-ELSEIF blocks, someone told me that I should use SWTICH instead, is it bad is I use 32 IF-ELSEIF blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case labels are constants.
Consider adding a static method in the enum class:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    TEST1("test1"), TEST2("test2");

    private String name;
    TestEnum(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public static TestEnum fromName(String name) {
        for (TestEnum e: values()) {
            if (e.name.equals(name)) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Name not found: " + name);
    }
}
```

You will then be able to write a switch statement:

```
switch (TestEnum.fromName(name)) {
case TEST1:
    //...
    break;
case TEST2:
    //...
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but I still do not see anything when I try to see options with TestNum, I get the same screen as shown in my question.

Comment: @pjj I guess it's trying to find a string constant, which doesn't exist in TestEnum.

Comment: Note that by calling `TestEnum.fromName(name)` run the risk of an `IllegalArgumentException` if your string doesn't match any of the Enum values - see [documentation for Enum#valueOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf\(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String\)).

Comment: @Rodrigue yes, you could change `fromName` to return `null` when the name is not found. In that case, you would need to test the result before the switch statement.

Comment: @Rodrigue Why do you think his solution has a loop hole, he is not at all using `valueOf`, I think he solution is good.

Comment: @pjj there was an edit to the response and when I made my comment @Maurice was using `valueOf`.

Comment: @Rodrigue I don't believe I ever used `valueOf`.

Comment: I concur with Maurice, and we can clearly see there is no edit history hyperlink in his answer. Thank you @MauricePerry for your answer, it solved my code issue.

Comment: @MauricePerry, correct, not sure where I got the `valueOf` from (probably mixed up with another response) but I guess my point was that the `switch` statement can throw an exception depending on the value of the string and that maybe it would be nicer to not throw in the method but instead handle that case in the `default` part of the `switch`.

Comment: @Rodrigue you mean by adding a constant `NONE_OF_THE_ABOVE`? I prefer throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own method to convert a string value to your enum.

For example, this is the approach that I always use:

```
public enum TestEnum {
    // Enum constants
    // Enum fields, constructors, etc..

    public static TestEnum fromName(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(e -> e.name.equals(name))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Now the resulting enum can now be used in the `switch` statement

Comment: Thanks for your time to reply

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using `String` constants instead of an `Enum`. For instance:

```
public class TestEnum {

    private static final String TEST1 = "test1";
    private static final String TEST2 = "test2";

}
```

could then be used in a `switch` statement like so:

```
switch(name) {
    case TestEnum.TEST1:
        break;
    case TestEnum.TEST2:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Completion in your IDE should then give you the options `TEST`, `TEST2`, ... .

Comment: Thanks for your time to reply. I know about I want to achieve it using ENUM.